# Customer Token by Customer Session

Tags: magento-2.1, addtocart, rest-api, php-7

I am trying to add items to my cart by using the magento 2 Rest API.

Is it possible to get the Customer token by using the customer session? 
I have looked into this and tried to implement a mix of a few ways to get the results i require.

```
public function getCustomerToken(){
  $result = "null";

  $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
  $customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');

  if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
    $customerToken = $this->tokenModelFactory->create();
    $tokenKey = $customerToken->createCustomerToken($customerSession->getCustomer()->getId())->getToken();
    $result = $tokenKey;
  }
  else{
    $result = "null";
  }
  return $result;
}
```

This is what i have so far. This is currently throwing an error

`Undefined property: Vendor\Module\Block\Index\Index::$tokenModelFactory`

To add the items to the cart I need 3 things, the product sku, the quantity and the QuoteID.

to get the quote ID, i must create a cart for the user and to do this i need the customers token.

This is the article I have been learning from:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/get-started/order-tutorial/order-create-quote.html

Is it possible to do what i am trying to?

Thanks

Comment: You don't need to do any of that. Have a look at the answer by @BigDaddyL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my own experiences, I could only seem to get the customer token using this  -

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/get-started/order-tutorial/order-create-customer.html#get-token

This passes over the users email and password to get it, which isn't ideal.

I tried using the "/mine" and "/me" endpoint as well, but after Magento 2.1.7 or so, this no longer works.

I have achieved something similar to you though by using the customer email address to get their customer ID, and from this you can add items to their cart using -

```
/rest/V1/customers/{customerID}/carts
```

This gives back a cart ID (quote ID)  that can be used.

This method uses an admin bearer token in the request, which lets you add items to a customers / guest carts.

---

Edited in example -

The headers for these requests would look like -

[image: bearertoken]

Obviously with the generated admin bearer token.

Do a **GET** to `/rest/V1/customers/search`

Use the params to fill in the customer you're trying to finds email address (i'm using Postman here to test) -

[image]

Making the endpoint - `/rest/V1/customers/search?searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][field]=email&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][value]=email@address.com&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][condition_type]=eq`

This will return information about the customer, including the customer ID -

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "group_id": 1,
            "default_billing": "3",
            "created_at": "2017-08-31 15:41:04",
            "updated_at": "2017-08-31 15:41:04",
            "created_in": "Default Store View",
........
```

You can also filter the response down to only get the email address (http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/howdoi/webapi/search-criteria.html) but i'll skip that for now.

Now that you have the customer ID, you can start to populate their cart.

**POST** to `/rest/V1/customers/{customerID}/carts`

The response here will be used as the quote ID. For this example I will use "62" as the quote ID.

Now if you do a **GET** to `rest/V1/carts/62`

You will be able to see what parts still need filled in (product, shipping, billing, payment etc).

You can pretty much use this guide - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/get-started/order-tutorial/order-add-items.html to complete the order. Instead of using the **/carts/mine** endpoint, you'd replace **/mine** with the quote ID from earlier.

If you want me to finish the example fully, let me know.

Comment: cheers for your response. I am glad i am on the right track with it.

Comment: im unsure of how i would put what you said into practise.

could you please give me an example of how to implement it? i know how to get the admin token but unsure how to set the headers and content of the request up.

thanks

Comment: I edited in an example that will hopefully help. I didn't add how to get the customers email address though, i'm using a custom integrated service to do this - so giving an example of this part wouldn't help.